# IFERROR show decimal values instead of hour format

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using IFERROR formula in excel, normally it works well, 
but when the value is in hour format, I get a strange decimal value.

For example:

```
=IFERROR(A1, "")
```

When A1's value is 10:00, the result is 0.416666667.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Format you cell to "hh:mm:ss", or use `=TEXT(IFERROR(A1,""),"hh:mm:ss")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this formula: `Scott Craner` already mentioned it on comment. I just figure it in excel and put screenshot make it more clear.

```
=TEXT(IFERROR(A1, ""),"hh:mm:ss am/pm")
```

[image]